# Why doesn't the 0th index of this array still equal 0?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

In the following code, the line `to_string(foo1->_bar[0])` returns `"0"` as one would expect. However, the line `to_string(foo2->_bar[0])` returns some other (seemingly random) integer. Why is this? What could I do to make my code function in the intended way? (I.e., cause the default constructor of `Foo` to assign an integer array equal to `{0}` to `_bar`.)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    int* _bar;
    Foo() {
        int bar[1] = {0};
        this->_bar = bar;
    }
    Foo(int* bar) {
        this->_bar = bar;
    }
};

int main()
{    
    int bar[1] = {0};
    Foo* foo1 = new Foo(bar);
    cout << to_string(foo1->_bar[0]) << "\n";

    Foo* foo2 = new Foo();
    cout << to_string(foo2->_bar[0]) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `foo2` case, `bar[1]` is a local array variable inside the constructor. It won't be accessible once the constructor ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `foo2` case, `bar[1]` is a local array variable inside the constructor. It won't be accessible once the constructor ends.

And since you're storing it as a pointer, when that space on the stack gets used for anything else, you'd get data from that location; likely garbage.

If `bar[1]` inside the constructor were a `static` variable, it would work for you. Of course, I understand that it's just a test code and you'd not do it in real code.

Answer (score 2):

In default constructor case you are declaring bar[1] as a local variable to constructor and this->_bar points to a memory location of the bar. Since bar[1] scope ends at the last line of the constructor foo2 will be pointing to some garbage value instead of 0.You can do something like this or declare bar[1] as a static variable.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int* _bar;
        int bar = 0;
        Foo() {
            this->_bar = &bar;
        }
        Foo(int* bar) {
        this->_bar = bar;
   }
};
```